# Seaborn TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, error-handling, seaborn, typeerror

I have the following code that when I run it, I keep getting a "TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'" message.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
print(tips.head())

sns.barplot(x='tip', y='total_bill', data=tips)

plt.show()
```

I've adjusted line 84 in algorithms.py file in anaconda3 to:

```
resampler = integers(0, n, n, dtype=np.int_)
```

This doesn't seem to fix the issue. The current versions I'm running are:
Pandas: 1.0.3
Numpy: 1.18.2
Seaborn: 0.10.0

Comment: Adjusted code from above - 'sex' inserted for 'tip':

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
print(tips.head())

sns.barplot(x='tip', y='total_bill', data=tips)

plt.show()

Answer (score 1):

I had seaborn 0.10.0 version. I was getting same error. I installed seaborn 0.9.0 version.
Run below command in Command prompt:

1. activate
2. python -mpip install seaborn==0.9.0

After installing , i tried to run and error got resolved.
Hope this would work for you too.